# how to install hp photosmart 6520

Tags: printing, hp

There are three ways to define this printer to my Ubuntu 20.10 (CUPS, Settings, HPLIP), and a myriad of options.
I cannot seem to find one that works for Photos, although CUPS Print Test Page works.
Sometimes I get "Filter failure".
Sometimes I get a blank page.
Sometimes I cannot set the paper type, or the tray, or the paper size.
Sometimes I get "Paper Mismatch".

Comment: All supported HP can be installed with the official HP installer (that is the HPLIP option you mention and that one will be the most feature rich option).  1st website to look out for is openprinting: https://www.openprinting.org/printer/HP/HP-DeskJet_6520 Comment from website: For advanced functionality such as printer status and maintenance features, use the HPLIP driver (which includes HPIJS). Link https://developers.hp.com/hp-linux-imaging-and-printing/

Comment: You have a modern printer and would be best served by using a wireless connection. (Using USB with such a printer is fraught on Ubuntu 20.10). See https://wiki.debian.org/CUPSQuickPrintQueues HPLIP is completely unrequired.

Comment: Didn't notice you have 20.10 and not 20.04. My comment ("fraught") applies only to 20.04. 20.10 should be ok with USB.

Comment: HPLIP worked.I was sure that I tried that way already.
But it's working now. Thank you.